# labels with geom_text ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Hy guys, 
I have a df and with this code

```
ggplot(logger) + geom_line(aes(Date.time, T, group=ID, colour=ID))+
  ggtitle("Temperature in piezometers") +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Temperature")
```

I can made this graph:
[image]

That's fine, but is there a way to add ID labels directly on the graph just next to the end of the lines? I mean, replace the legend with a direct on graph labeling.
I guess it should be done with `geom_text` function, but all my attempts failed.

Comment: this could help: http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/directlabels-adding-direct-labels-to-ggplot2-and-lattice-plots/

Comment: Can you give an example of the `geom_text` code that failed?

Comment: I believe the package **directlabels** is intended for this sort of thing.

Comment: @HarrisonJones for example, typing geom_text(aes(label=ID)) gives me this error: Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y. But if I add the x and y so the code becomes geom_text(aes(x=Date.time, y=T,label=ID)) ggplot adds a label for every single observation. Givent that I had almost 5000 observations for every ID the graph looks terrible.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new data.frame with the positions of the labels

[image: the plot]

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(12345)
dataset <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(seq_len(5), function(i){
    data.frame(
      ID = i,
      Time = 1:100,
      Temp = as.vector(arima.sim(model = list(ar = .8), n = 100))
    )
  }) 
)
dataset$ID <- factor(dataset$ID)
Right <- subset(dataset, Time == max(Time))
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Time, y = Temp, colour = ID)) + geom_line() + geom_text(data = Right, aes(label = ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `annotate`. This gives you a bit more flexibility, though you would have to specify where you want the annotation to be.

See documentation: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/annotate.html